# Azure Function Deployment while Running

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Let's say I have an Azure Function named **func** running. In the middle of **func** running, I deploy some new changes to the **func**. Will **func** finish the current run and then start with the new changes or will the current run just end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-zero-downtime-deployment

*The reliable execution model of Durable Functions requires that orchestrations be deterministic, which creates an additional challenge to consider when you deploy updates. When a deployment contains changes to activity function signatures or orchestrator logic, in-flight orchestration instances fail. This situation is especially a problem for instances of long-running orchestrations, which might represent hours or days of work.
To prevent these failures from happening, you have two options:*

- *Delay your deployment until all running orchestration instances have completed.*
- *Make sure that any running orchestration instances use the existing versions of your functions.*

Comment: -1 as this doesn't answer the question. The quoted documentation is about *Azure Durable Functions*, not Azure Functions. Azure Durable Functions is an orchestration technique. The documentation is saying that if you're using Durable Functions and you deploy new function signatures, in-flight Durable Functions orchestrations will also fail. It doesn't address individual function deployment downtime.